# Could not find Pixman - Cmake error

Tags: build, cmake, zlib, cairo, libpng

I was building [Cairo](https://github.com/CMakePorts/cairo) using cmake Gui.
When I hit 'configure', Cmake is showing the following error:

> Could NOT find PIXMAN, try to set the path to PIXMAN root folder in
>   the system variable PIXMAN (missing: PIXMAN_LIBRARIES
>   PIXMAN_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
>   Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY
>   ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
>  CMake Error at
>   C:/cmake-3.7.0-rc1-win32-x86/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138
>   (message): 
> Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY
>   PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   C:/cmake-3.7.0-rc1-win32-x86/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   C:/cmake-3.7.0-rc1-win32-x86/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:146
>   (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

I have downloaded Zlib, LibPng, Pixman source files.
Where to place these files?
I think FindPixaman.cmake file needs to be modified:

```
 # PIXMAN_ROOT_DIR - Set this variable to the root installation of PIXMAN
```

How to set path of `PIXMAN_ROOT_DIR` to root installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think FindPixaman.cmake file needs to be modified

You should never modify a package file. What you should do is set the variable `PIXMAN_ROOT_DIR` in your cmake project before the call to `find_package` so the package will know where to search:

```
set(PIXMAN_ROOT_DIR /path/to/pixman)
```

Where `/path/to/pixman` is the directory where pixman is installed. Looking in the [package file](https://github.com/CMakePorts/cairo/blob/cmake/cmake/FindPixman.cmake#L42), it should contain sub-directories `include` and `lib` containing `pixman.h` and the compiled library respectively.

Alternatively you can set `PIXMAN_ROOT_DIR` in the gui using button `Add entry`:

[image]